# how to return an array of serialized objects via Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a user who has a list of liked items. I'd like to create a serializer that returns this. For a single items, I would have something like this:

```
class UserProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :liked_items2

  def liked_items2
    ItemLikedSerializer.new(object.liked_items).attributes
  end
end
```

but how would I return an array of liked items and apply ItemLikedSerializer to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is did it:

```
class UserProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name #, :liked_items

  has_many :liked_items, embed: :object, serializer: ItemLikedSerializer
end
```